# How to determine if the process is martingale?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales, stochastic-analysis, local-martingales

I have that $\{X_t; t=1,2... \}$ is an i.i.d random variables such that $P(X_t=1)=p=1/4$ and $P(X_t=-1)=1-p=3/4$. Let $S_0=0$ and $S_t=\sum_{i=1}^tX_i$ for $t=1,2...$ 
Let finally $Y_t=a^{S_t}$ for $t=0,1,2...$ where $a$ is a constant (not zero). 
The question is, for which values of $a$ is $Y_t; t=0,1,2..$ a martingale with respect to $X_t; t=0,1,2... ? \quad$ 
Could somebody help me with this? I have tried with the definition of a martingale $E[a^{\sum_ {i=1}^{t+1}X_i}|X_t, X_{t-1}...]$ but I am stuck here

Comment: You mean $X_t \sim \mathrm{Ber}(p)$?

Comment: You have typed $X_t=1$ at both places.

Comment: I am so sorry guys. It was a mistake by me. I have corrected it now.

Comment: $X_t$ is not a Bernouli trial no

Comment: Do you mean $X_t=-1$ or $X_t =-11$?

Comment: yes @Kavi Rama Murthy

Comment: I mean that $X_t=-1$

Answer (score 1):

$E[a^{\sum_ {i=1}^{t+1}X_i}|X_t, X_{t-1}...]=a^{\sum_ {i=1}^{t+1}X_i}Ea^{X_t}$. So we get a martinagle if and only if $Ea^{X_t}=1$ for all $t$. Can you compute $Ea^{X_t}$ and solve $Ea^{X_t}=1$ for $a$?

Comment: I have now corrected it